# Adding textfield to Graphics in java

Tags: java, graphics, render, jtextfield, bufferstrategy

Does anyone know how to add `JTextField` into Graphics name `bufferstrategy.getDrawGraphics`?
Tryed to pain it into graphics, something like this:

```
private JTextField Input = new JTextField();
BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();

if (bs == null) {
    createBufferStrategy(3);
    return;
}

final Graphics gCommands = bs.getDrawGraphics();
Graphics gCC = bs.getDrawGraphics();
Input.requestFocus();
Input.paint(gCC);
Input.setBounds(800,250, 350,20);
Input.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 0));
Input.setEditable(true);
Input.setBackground(getBackground());
Input.setForeground(getForeground());
Input.addKeyListener(key);
```

But, eventhough it displayed, I could not edit it. Even the `Input.setBounds(800,250, 350,20)` did not work. This method that is written above, is being called inside a gameloop. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What went wrong? Did you get a runtime error? Did it display?

Comment: It displayed, although the `JTextField` was not editable

Comment: Is the class a Canvas? JFrame?

Comment: It extends Canvas, yes

Comment: Canvas is an AWT component.  Did you try with a java.awt.TextField?  Alternatively, can you try painting to a JPanel instead of a Canvas to use the JTextField?  Either way, I think you should be adding the textfield to a backing component instead of to the graphics.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Painting a component on a `Graphics` won't make it a "live" component.  Components need to be added to a valid container that is attached to a native peer before they become live.

At the moment, the only thing you are doing is producing a "rubber stamp"/image of the component on the surface of the graphics context.

There are some tricks to this, as the painting process expects that the component is attached to a valid, native peer.

First, you must prepare the field...

```
Input.setBounds(800,250, 350,20);
Input.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 0));
Input.setEditable(true);
Input.setBackground(getBackground());
Input.setForeground(getForeground());
```

Then you need to paint it.  The field will not automatically repaint, again, this has to do with the field not been attached to a native peer...

```
Input.printAll(gCC);
```

If you want a life component, you are going to have to add the component to the container.  This may be problematic when using a buffer strategy...

Swing components are already double buffered.